# Error when registering for an event - DB Error no such table

Tags: civievent

Hello I am getting the following error when trying to register for an event. Not sure what is happening or which table is missing. I am running CiviCRM 5.2.13 on CentOS Linux/Plesk 17. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
backTrace

#0 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type [nativecode=1146 ** T...")
#3 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type [nativecode=1146 ** T...")
#4 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type [nativecode=1146 ** T...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, "SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type [nativecode=1146 ** T...", "1146 ** Table 'jtaweb_crm.node' doesn't exist")
#7 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type")
#9 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type")
#10 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type")
#11 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type")
#12 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1413): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type", TRUE)
#13 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.pogstone.contenttokens/contenttokens.php(492): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT type FROM .node n where status = 1 GROUP BY type", (Array:0))
#14 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.pogstone.contenttokens/contenttokens.php(9): contenttokens_getContentTypesInUse()
#15 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(270): contenttokens_civicrm_tokens((Array:5))
#16 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php(84): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:242), "civicrm_tokens", 1, (Array:5), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#17 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(86): CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invokeViaUF(1, (Array:5), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_tokens")
#18 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_tokens", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#19 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_tokens", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#20 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_tokens", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#21 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(164): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_tokens", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#22 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(751): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:1), (Array:5), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_tokens")
#23 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Individual.php(208): CRM_Utils_Hook::tokens((Array:5))
#24 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(168): CRM_Contact_BAO_Individual::format((Array:36), Object(CRM_Contact_DAO_Contact))
#25 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(308): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::add((Array:36))
#26 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(2011): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:36))
#27 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php(1190): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact((Array:42), (Array:18), "2", (Array:0), NULL, "Individual", TRUE)
#28 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php(523): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm::updateContactFields("2", (Array:42), (Array:18), Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm))
#29 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(489): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm->postProcess()
#30 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#31 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next", "Next")
#32 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")
#33 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")
#34 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#35 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#36 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#37 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#38 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#39 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", "register")
#40 /data/www/vhosts/<website url>/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#41 {main}
```

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to member your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such table
Return to home page.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the backtrace it looks like its a bug in Fancy Tokens extension. There is a new release for this extension. Try after upgrading the extension to [5.1](https://github.com/sgladstone/com.pogstone.fancytokens/archive/5.1.zip) if you can still replicate the bug.

Cheers

Pradeep